# two queries distinct and insertion gives error

Tags: php, mysql

i wanted to make sure there's no double booked for any dates. i've used both select distinct and insert query in order to call the data. but still, the data can still be duplicate.

here's the whole code:

```
<?php
                error_reporting(0);

                  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jpn");
                  $rol_no=@$_POST["rol_no"];
                  $ic=@$_POST["ic"];
                  $start=@$_POST["tarikh"];
                  $end=@$_POST["tarikhakhir"];
                  $bil=@$_POST["bilangan"];
                  $title=@$_POST["sebab"];
 //insertion data tempahan
                  $sql="INSERT INTO tempahan(ic,start,end,bil,title) VALUES ('$ic','$start','$end','$bil','$title')
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                    UPDATE
                    ic='$ic'
                    ,start ='$start'
                    ,end='$end'
                    ,bil='$bil'
                    ,title='$title'
                    ";

 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                  if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($con,$result))
                  {
                      $rol_no=$row[0];
                      $ic=$row[1];
                      $start=$row[2];
                      $end=$row[3];
                      $bil=$row[4];
                      $title=$row[5];

                  }
 //distinct data to avoid duplicate for date
                  $sql2= "SELECT DISTINCT start, end
                        FROM tempahan
                        ORDER BY start, end";
                  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) 
                  {
                      echo "<script>alert('duplicate tarikh')</script>";
                  }
 ?>
```

Comment: [RTFM on `mysqli_fetch_array()`.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use unique indexes for unique fields/set of fields. It is required and enough to guarantee uniqueness. And then, do insert with IGNORE option or with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Without unique indexes they are not working.